# How to acces factory's functions from its other functions in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwt

I am really trying to get a hold on how all of this works. I feel like this should work. I have an Auth factory and when the jwt is expired it calls its method 'delegate' which gets a new token with the refresh token. For some reason I get the error '_this.delegate is not a function'. (I am doing delegate in both cases for testing purposes)

```
webapp.factory('Auth', function($http, API_URL, $window, $location, jwtHelper ) {
var _this = this;
    var delegate = function(){
        $http.post(API_URL+'/admin/delegate', {refresh_token: $window.sessionStorage.refreshToken } ).success(function(result) {
            $window.sessionStorage.authToken = result.token;
            $window.sessionStorage.refreshToken = result.refresh_token;
            console.log('delegate-result: '+JSON.stringify(result));
            $location.path('/about');
            //LocalService.set('authToken', JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    };
    return {
        //returns true if there is an auth token
        isAuthenticated: function() {
            var storedJwt = $window.sessionStorage.authToken;
            console.log('stored JWT: '+storedJwt);
            var storedPayload = jwtHelper.decodeToken(storedJwt);
            console.log('payload: '+JSON.stringify(storedPayload));
            if(jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(storedJwt)){
                console.log('is expired expired: '+jwtHelper.getTokenExpirationDate(storedJwt));
                _this.delegate();
            } else {
                console.log('is not expired expires: '+jwtHelper.getTokenExpirationDate(storedJwt));
                //For testing
                _this.delegate();
            }
            return $window.sessionStorage.authToken;
            //LocalService.get('authToken');
        },
        delegate: delegate,
        //login function, should be moved to login controller
        login: function(email, password) {
            var login = $http.post(API_URL+'/authenticate', {email: email, password: password } );
            login.success(function(result) {
                console.log('login-result: '+JSON.stringify(result));
                $window.sessionStorage.authToken = result.token;
                $window.sessionStorage.refreshToken = result.refresh_token;
                $location.path('/about');
                //LocalService.set('authToken', JSON.stringify(result));
            });
            return login;
        },
```

Comment: there is no `delegate()` in the `isAuthenticated` function, so `this.delegate()` will be undefined, because of how closures work in JavaScript.

Comment: @Claies ok so I added a reference to the factory beforehand and still seeing the same error:

`webapp.factory('Auth', function($http, API_URL, $window, $location, jwtHelper ) {
  var _this = this;
  return { ... _this.delegate(); ...` triggers _this.delegate() is not a function. I changed the example code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove `_this` from `_this.delegate()`.

The function `delegate()` is in scope where you are using it.

There is nothing wrong with using `var` in a `factory`. A `service` is different